# Evaluating boolean expression with recursive

Tags: c

I've wrote a program to recursively evaluate boolean expression. But when I run with input `"(1|1)"`, in the second recursion of function S, specifically in line `result = result || P()` instead of step into `P()`, it passes the line and returns result. However it works fine with input `"(~1|1)"`. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *s;
char *f;
bool P(), A();

// The grammar is:
// S -> P||S | P&&S | P
// P -> A | ~A
// A -> (S) | 0 | 1

bool S() {
    bool result = P(); 
    if (*s == '|') {
        s++; 
        result = result || P(); 
    } 
    else
        if (*s == '&') {
            s++; 
            result = result && P(); 
        } 
    return result;
}

bool P() {
    if (*s == '~') {
        s++;
        return !A();
    }
    else
    {
        return A(); 
    }
}

bool A() {
    bool result;
    if (*s == '(') {
        s++;
        result = S();
        if (*s == ')') s++;
        else {
            printf("Syntaktisch falsch! Stelle %ld, Art: Anzahl von '(' und ')' sind nicht gleich\n", s-f);
            exit(1);
        }
    } 
    else
        if (*s == '1') {
            s++;
            result = true; 
        }
        else
            if (*s == '0') {
                s++;
                result = false; 
            }
            else {
                printf("Syntaktisch falsch! Stelle: %ld, Art: Boolscher Ausdruck fehlt\n", s-f); // Hier gibt Fehlermeldung aus, wenn Input String ist nur '~'. 
                exit(1);
            }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool result;
    if (argc != 2) exit(1);
    s = argv[1];
    f = s;
    result = S();
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Global variables are a bad idea. 2. Use meaningful function names. 3. Use meaningful variable names

Comment: @EdHeal I can understand why you wrote that, but in this context (pun intended) the names of the variables and functions makes complete sense. I would also have chosen to write them without using acronyms, but in this code I don't think it's that bad. Given the grammar, it's very clear what's happening.

Comment: @klutt even though I upvoted Ed's comment on general principles, you raise a good point.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  because it is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  for functions like: `printf()`

Comment: regarding: `bool P(), A();`   1) separate prototypes onto separate line.  2) some of the prototypes are missing  3) when a function does not take any parameters, then the prototype should have `void` between the parens, otherwise the compiler will generate code that allows ANY parameters (including no parameters)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) regarding statements like: `if (*s == ')') s++;`  Please follow the axiom: *only statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent) 5) please do not omit optional braces '{' and '}'

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (argc != 2)  exit(1);`  This does not inform the user of what happened.  From the users viewpoint, the program just suddenly exited.  Suggest:  `if (argc != 2)  { fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s paramMeaning\n", argv[0] );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: Please explain what the command line parameter is expected to contain?   Please use meaningful variable names.  Please use meaningful function names, including some active verb.  As it is, we have no idea what the program is trying to perform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result || P()` only requires that ONE of the values - `result` *OR* `P()` - be TRUE in order to satisfy the expression. If `result` is TRUE when `result || P()` is evaluated the function is not required to be called - this is known as "short-circuit evaluation". Change your code to:

```
bool p_val;

p_val = P();
result = result || p_val;
```

in order to ensure that the function is actually invoked.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this is the first time I hear about this xD

Comment: And thank *you* for posting a well-written question.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = result || P();
```

`P` will never will called if `result` is the `true`

```
result = result && P();
```

`P` will never will called if `result` is `false`

so place the call first to make sure it is called.

```
P() || result
P() && result
```

it is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation